# Convertir html2canvas a formato base64

Tags: javascript, html2canvas

Tengo la siguiente duda..

estoy convirtiendo el contenido del div "html-content-holder" a imagen, de momento mi codigo funciona bien, si lo pinto en un div "previewImg" se muestra sin problema, ahora lo que quiero es convertir esa imagen a formato base64, actualmente estoy intentandolo asi:

```
html2canvas(
  document.getElementById("html-content-holder")
).then(function (canvas) {
  var anchorTag = document.createElement("a");
  document.body.appendChild(anchorTag);

  document.getElementById("previewImg").appendChild(canvas);
  let imgbase64 = canvas[0].toDataURL();
  $('#valsign1').val(imgbase64);
});
```

Cuando intento pasar el valor de la imagen a base64 en mi id "valsign1", en la consola me pinta el error ..

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toDataURL')

Alguien sabe como puedo pasar esa imagen que se muestra bien aqui ..

```
document.getElementById("previewImg").appendChild(canvas);
```

pero al tratar de convertirla a base64 no es posible debido al error que les menciono..

Gracias de antemano

Comment: `canvas[0].toDataURL()` -> `canvas.toDataURL()` ?

Comment: @alo Malbarez gracias por tu respuesta! Con esa opcion me marca el mismo error!

Comment: `console.log(((canvas is instanceof HTMLCanvasElement)?'':'no') + ' es un canvas');`

Comment: `canvas` no es un array... por lo que debería ser `canvas.toDataURL()`. Haz un log a `imgbase64` y comenta que te da.

Comment: alo Malbarez Unexpected identifier 'is'

Comment: Cris223511.dev Gracias por tu respuesta, al cambiar la opcion como suguieres y al hacer un log de imgbase64 me tira este error: DOMException: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.

Comment: Si no me equivoco, es por restricciones de seguridad en los navegadores, más información [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22710627/tainted-canvases-may-not-be-exported).

Answer (score 1):

Gracias a las respuestas de todos!

Saludo especial a alo Malbarez y Cris223511.dev, como lo mencionó Cris223511.dev el problema tenia que ver con con problemas de seguridad del navegador, la solución fue pasar mi proyecto a un servidor local Xampp y desde ahí modificar el uso de CORS a true..

dejo el código por si le sirve a alguien

```
html2canvas(document.getElementById("html-content-holder"), {useCORS:true}).then(function (canvas) {
  var anchorTag = document.createElement("a");
  document.body.appendChild(anchorTag); ....
```